# An urn contains five balls numbered 1 to 5. We conduct a sample of two balls with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

Please let me know if my answers are correct or not.

(a) Draw a diagram to represent the sample space for this experiment. Mark the following events on your diagram:

E1 first ball is a 5,
E2 second ball drawn has a value less than 4,
E3 sum of the values of the two draws is greater than or equal to 8.

(b) Evaluate P(E1), P(E2), and P(E3).

(c) Repeat parts (a) and (b) assuming no replacement.

**Answers**

E1: 1/5 (As there are five possibilities and we have to draw the ball 5)

E2: 3/5 (As there are three balls that have value less then 4)

E3: 6/25 (There would be six events resulting in value greater then or equal to 8).

**(C) Without Replacement**

E1: 1/5

E2: 3/4

E3: 4/20 = 1/5

Please correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your E2 for C) (without replacement) is incorrect.  It should still be $\frac{3}{5}$.

Think of it like this: suppose you draw all five balls without replacement, i.e. you effectively shuffle them and then line them up.  Then the probability of *any* of them (no matter what position they are in the line-up) being smaller than $4$ is $\frac{3}{5}$

If you still don't believe me:

If the first ball is smaller than $4$ (which has a probability of $\frac{3}{5}$), then the probability of the second ball also being smaller than $4$ is $\frac{2}{4}$.  But if the first ball is $4$ or greater (which has a probability of $\frac{2}{5}$), then the probability of the second ball  being smaller than $4$ is $\frac{3}{4}$. So:

$$P(E2) = \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} + \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{5}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain why? We already drew the ball number 5 out right? So our sample space now contains 4 balls?

Comment: @AliShan No, event E2 does not require that we draw $5$ as the first ball ... it only focuses on what the second ball is.

Comment: Thanks alot, I got it now :) Thanks for clarification.